# I'm having trouble with formula,program runs fine but the answer seems to be wrong

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The following program should calculate the distance between two points:

#### header.h

```
class point{
private:
    double x, y, length;
public:
    point();
    point(double a, double b);

    int set_length(point,point);
};
```

#### header.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"header.h"
#include<math.h> 
using namespace std;

point::point() :x(0), y(0) { }

point::point(double a, double b){
    x = a;
    y = b;
}

int point::set_length(point p1, point p2){

    length = sqrt(((p2.x - p1.x)*(p2.x - p1.x)) +
                  ((p2.y - p1.y)*(p2.y -p1.y)));
    return length;
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"header.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    point p1(4, 1);
    point p2(8, 2);

    point length;

    cout << length.set_length(p1, p2) << endl;
}
```

The answer should be `3` but its not.

Could someone help me implement the distance formula?

Comment: BTW, the `main` function returns `int`.  Always.

Comment: Enlighten yourself, use a debugger to execute each statement, one at a time and *watch* the values of the variables.  This is a good example to practice with.

Comment: I recommend using temporary variables to hold values in your `set_length` function.  This will allow you to see the values in each step.

Comment: can you please tell me how i'm a student and so not good in programming

Comment: Example: `const double x_diff = p2.x - p1.x; const double y_diff = p2.y - p1.y; const double x_squared = x_diff * xdiff; const double y_squared = y_diff * y_diff; length = sqrt(x_squared + y_squared);`.  You can insert `cout` statements after each statement or use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the actual output you get, but, here are possible causes of errors:

1. You're on a UNIX-like system and you didn't give `-lm` parameter to the linker, thus the math library is not linked in, and you get weird behavior. You can also get similar problems if you don't link the math library on some other systems. So, be sure to link the math library.
2. You are returning `int` from `point::set_lenght` which will do a cast from `double` - a cast is *not* rounding, most likely it's truncating. Change to return `double`.

BTW, distance between points (4,1) and (8,2) is *not* 3. It's something like 4.12310563.

Comment: answer is noy rounding off

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should probably read something about [file organization](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Programming_Languages/C%2B%2B/Code/File_Organization).

Regarding you code, the formula for distance between two points, let's say A (x<sub>1</sub> , y<sub>1</sub>) and B (x<sub>2</sub> , y<sub>2</sub>) is:

[image]

which in code looks like:

```
int x1, x2, y1, y2;

Point A(x1, x2), B(y1, y2);

double distance = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));
```

some casting may be necessary inside the `pow` or `sqrt` as the coordinates are `int`s.

In class `point` the function should be named `double get_lenght()` to avoid implicit conversions of the returned result and to make sense, as you are not *setting* but rather *getting* the distance.

---

Side note: This function shouldn't be part of the class as it involves two points in the class called `point`, it is logically more suitable for class named `line` probably.